# How to fix insta-crash on dual booting Windows 8 from separate drive

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I've had Ubuntu as the sole OS on my desktop for a couple years.  Updated it to Precise soon after it came out.  Today I decided to try dual booting to Windows 8.  I bought a new, separate hard drive (SATA) to install Windows on.  My Ubuntu installation is on my older PATA disk.

I disconnected the Ubuntu drive completely when installing Windows.  It seemed to go OK.

I've now re-attached the disk with Ubuntu on it.  I was able to boot to Ubuntu, run update-grub, and see that it recognized Windows 8.  I now have a Windows 8 option in grub on startup.

However, when I select that option I get a couple seconds of the Windows boot screen, followed by a *very* brief flash of a "Your PC needs to restart" error message (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNzTk.jpg), and then the computer spontaneously reboots, and I end up back at the grub screen.

I'm not sure what to try next.  Is this a windows security measure to prevent the OS from being loaded by some malicious bootloader?  Is the mysterious "uefi" somehow to blame?  Have I missed something obvious?

EDIT: This seems to be the same problem as [Dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu, separate HDD, Win8 boot failure from GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125223/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-separate-hdd-win8-boot-failure-from-grub?rq=1), but the accepted answer there is to buy a $25 copy of EasyBCD and boot from Windows. :(

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).